# Installing python 3.6.3 using chef on Ubunbu 16.04

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to install python 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 using chef cookbooks [poise-python](https://github.com/poise/poise-python) and seem to be going aroud in circles. I've tried various differnet methods using the docs but none seem to work.

I've trid adding these after including the recipe

```
python_runtime '3.6.3'

python_runtime '3' do
options version: '3.6'
end
```

I've tried these in the attributes.

```
node.default['poise-python']['poise_python_version'] = '3.6.3'
node.default['poise-python']['version'] = '3.6.3'
```

I've tried to install the version I want i na virtual enviroment

```
python_virtualenv '/opt/myapp' do   
group "group"   
python '3.6.3'   
action :create 
end
```

Any suggestions on how best to install the version of python I require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Python 3.6 package for Ubuntu 16.04 by default, they only offer [2.7 and 3.5](https://github.com/poise/poise-python/blob/master/lib/poise_python/python_providers/system.rb#L36). You can set up the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and then do something like this:

```
python_runtime '3.6' do
  provider :system # This is already the default on Ubuntu but restating for clarity
  options package_name: 'python3.6'
end
```